# Notifying all clients of data changes

Tags: ios, parse-platform

My iOS/Parse app allows multiple users to modify data which is shared among everyone. So if user 1 modifies the data I want the rest of the users to be notified of the change so that they can request the new data. I'd like this to happen in the background. So, if I have the app open and other user makes a change I want to get those changes as soon as possible (kind of like a shared notes app).

Does Parse support this type of data modification notification? If it doesn't I'd have to do something ugly like periodically poll for changes. :-(

Comment: You can use an `afterSave` cloud function to send a silent push notification to do this

Comment: It does sound like a good use for afterSave and push, but also note: those other clients probably don't need the new data until they are active.  You could just have them ask for what's new when they become active (and maybe after some interval has passed since they last asked).